# Signing Certificate for Xcode Content Notification Extension

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I am in the process of updating an old app to use UNUserNotification service and Notification Content Extension.  However, I have something strange going on with the provisioning profiles.

They are managed automatically by Xcode, however, my Debug Provisioning Profile for the Content Extension shows nothing?

[image]

I believe this to be the cause of a an issue I am currently having: My push server is unable to send notifications to my client devices when using the development signing certificate and the client is in debug mode.

Is there something I need to do to get around this? Or is this not anything important?